# How to read out a list of cases in one variable in SPSS and use that to add data?

Tags: spss

To explain my problem I use this example data set:

```
SampleID  Date          Project   Problem
03D00173  03-Dec-2010   1,00
03D00173  03-Dec-2010   1,00
03D00173  28-Sep-2009             YNTRAD    
03D00173  28-Sep-2009             YNTRAD
```

Now, the problem is that I need to replace the text "YNTRAD" with "YNTRAD_PILOT" but only for the cases with Date = 28-Sep-2009.

This is example is part of a much larger database, with many more cases having Project=YNTRAD and Data=28-Sep-2009, so I can not simply select first all cases with 28-Sep-2009, then check which of these cases have Project=YNTRAD and then replace. Instead, what I need to do is:

1. Look at each case that has a 1,00 in Problem (these are problem
   cases)
2. Then find the SampleID that corresponds with that sample
3. Then find all other cases with the same SampleID BUT WITH
   Date=28-Sep-2009 (this is needed because only those samples are part
   of a pilot study) and then replace YNTRAD in Project to
   YNTRAD_PILOT.

I read a lot about:

LOOP 
- DO REPEAT
- DO IF

but I don't know how to use these in solving this problem.

I first tried making a list containing only the sample ID's that need eventually to be changed (again, this is part of a much larger database).

```
STRING SampleID2 (A20).

IF (Problem=1) SampleID2=SampleID.
EXECUTE.

AGGREGATE
/OUTFILE=*
/BREAK=SampleID2
/n_SampleID2=N.
```

This gives a dataset with only the SampleID's for which a change should be made. However I don't know how to read out this dataset case by case and looking up each SampleID in the overall file with all the date and then change only those cases were Date = 28-Sep-2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like once we can identify the IDs that need to be changed we've done the tricky part here.  We can use `AGGREGATE` with `MODE=ADDVARIABLES` to add a problem Id counter variable to our dataset.  From there, it's as you'd expect.

```
* Add var IdProblemCnt to your database . Stores # of times a given Id had a record with Problem = 1.
AGGREGATE
 /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
 /BREAK=SampleId
 /IdProblemCnt=CIN(Problem, 1, 1) .
EXE .

* once we've identified the "problem" Ids we can use `RECODE` Project var.
DO IF (IdProblemCnt>0 AND Date = DATE.MDY(9,28,2009) .
  RECODE Project ('YNTRAD' = 'YNTRAD_PILOT') .
END IF .
EXE .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!